# Is there a way to get the context menu from Windows Explorer as the context menu in the Windows Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

When you right click an item in the Windows 10 start menu, it offers you a very limited amount of options. I'd like to open the right click context menu you get from the Windows Explorer. Is this possible in any way?

[Start menu context menu (sucks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO8zO.png)

[Windows Explorer context menu (what I want in the start menu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raB7A.png)

Thanks in advance.